# ¿Por qué las furgonetas de la policía se llaman "lecheras" en España?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos, españa

En España llamamos a las furgonetas de la policía **"lecheras"**. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cierto tipo de coches policiales usados hasta finales de los setenta o principios de los ochenta eran de un modelo idéntico al usado para el reparto de leche. Por eso se les denominaba de manera coloquial "lecheras" a estos furgones.
>
> Fuente: ["El habla de Málaga", por Antonio Pozo](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=es&id=Fl5dAAAAMAAJ&dq=origen+lechera+policia&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Cooperativa+Lechera+Malague%C3%B1a).

En los años 60 los coches y furgonetas de la policía eran de color blanco y los modelos eran los habituales de la época (Renault 4, Viasa SV-430 y DKW F-1000).

Aparte de ser el mismo modelo, al ser los furgones policiales en algún momento de color blanco (["Estudios de lingüística española", por Manuel Seco](https://books.google.es/books?id=FLF2iT9qZHQC&lpg=PA488&dq=origen%20de%20%22lechera%22%20policia&hl=es&pg=PA488#v=onepage&q=lechera%20furg%C3%B3n%20policial&f=false)), ayudó también a establecer la relación entre el furgón de la policía y el de la cooperativa lechera.

---

<sub>Kudos para [Walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13628/walen) y [Roetning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12825/roetnig) que han aportado vía comentarios estas referencias.</sub>

Comment: De nada, un placer ;)

Answer (score 9):

Porque `leche` es una manera coloquial de decir `torta` o `porrazo`. Del DRAE

> [Leche](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=p2P1b1drnDXX2PuZ6B1Z)
>
> 6. f. vulg. Trastazo, porrazo. *Se dio una leche con el coche*
> 7. f. vulg. bofetada (‖ golpe con la mano abierta). *Si no te estás quieto te daré una leche*

La policía se presentaría en un evento, como en una manifestación, disturbios, protestas, etc. con estas furgonetas y se dedicaría a "dar leches". Por tanto, al vehículo en el que viajan los que *dan leches* se le dice coloquialmente "*lechera*".

**Nota**: Soy consciente de que esta es una versión muy sesgada de ciertos hechos. No digo que sea cierta ni que la comparta. Simplemente, este término es jerga, y como tal tiene origen por u unos particular y coloquial que se ha extendido con el tiempo.

Comment: En tiempos de Franco, si te metían en una lechera era bastante habitual que te dieran al menos un par de leches, sí. También puede influir que las furgonetas de la policía no eran muy diferentes de las usadas hace años para el reparto de la leche (lecheras), aunque estuvieran pintadas de distinto color.

Comment: uhmmmm *También puede influir que las furgonetas de la policía no eran muy diferentes de las usadas hace años para el reparto de la leche* @Gorpik tienes mas info sobre esto?

Comment: @JordiCastilla No mucha, por eso lo pongo solo como comentario. Pero si miras fotos, verás que muchos modelos son parecidos: https://www.google.com/search?q=furgoneta+lechera&tbm=isch

Comment: Pues me temo que el nombre no tiene nada que ver con dar "leches". En los años 60 los coches y furgonetas de la policía eran de color blanco y los modelos eran los habituales de la época (Renault 4, Viasa SV-430 y DKW F-1000). En los años 70 se cambió al color gris y en los 80 al color marrón (de esa época viene el nombre de "maderos"). Con posterioridad más cambios de color, quedando en la actualidad en el color azul o blanco y azul.

Answer (score 2):

Se les decía lecheras debido a que eran los seat 131 rancheras e iban pintados de blanco totalmente, excepto las letras negras POLICIA. Y a los policías se les conocían como maderos, porque iban todo de color marrón.