# ¿Por qué en España "leche" significa "golpe"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, españa

Viendo una película vieja doblada al español de España tuve que adivinar que "me dieron leche" significa "me dieron un golpe". Pensé que era un juego de palabras del momento, pero después descubrí siguiendo [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14749/6915) que el uso aparece ni más ni menos que en la RAE.  Ejemplos:

> Vaya leche que se ha dado con la bici.
>
> ¡Como vuelvas a hacerlo, te doy una leche!

¿Alguien sabe de dónde proviene la palabra "leche" con significado de "golpe"? ¿Tiene relación con el alimento *leche*? ¿Se usa en otra parte además de España?

Comment: Puedes ver http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/por-qu%C3%A9-las-furgonetas-de-la-polic%C3%ADa-se-llaman-lecheras-en-espa%C3%B1a?lq=1

Comment: En Colombia cuando p.ej un entrenador/jefe hizo que su entrenado/empleado trabaje  extremadamente duro se dice que "le sacó la leche" pero "dar leche" no se usa por estos lados.

Comment: @mdewey Precisamente siguiendo ese link veo que la relación es a la inversa. A las furgonetas policiales les dicen lecheras _porque_ ahí "les dan leche" a los detenidos.

Comment: La verdad es que hay [millones de expresiones con la palabra leche](http://profesoresdeele.org/2015/06/01/expresiones-con-la-palabra-leche/) que además [varían según los países](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Leche.php). Lo que me dio que pensar es lo que se indica en [wikcionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/leche): _Primera enseñanza que se da a un niño_. Esta enseñanza también podría ser relativa a la hostia de la misa. Y, por similitud, igual que decimos "pegar una hostia", podría llegarse a "pegar una leche".

Comment: No puedo aportar mucho respecto al origen de esta asociación, pero "leche" es una de esas palabras "comodín" en el español. Se puede usar con [un montón de significados distintos](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/leche). Dar una leche o dar de leches, tener mala leche, ir a toda leche, ser la leche ... Incluso tiene un uso (obsoleto) como ["primera enseñanza que se le da un niño](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/leche). Todo esto no da pistas sobre el origen de la asociación, pero quiero recalcar que como muchos otros usos, tal vez sea sólo fruto de la casualidad y no de unas asociación logica

Comment: ¿Nos podrías dar el contexto del fragmento?

Comment: En este contexto, la palabra *leche* es contable y se debe usar con numeral o artículo. *Me dieron una leche*. Excepción: *me dieron de leches*, que significa *me dieron una paliza*.

Comment: En España, hay muchas expresiones con la palabra leche: Estar de mala leche, Tener mala leche, A mala leche, Ser la leche, De la leche, A toda leche, Echando leches, Darse una leche, Dar una leche, ¡Leche!, Cagarse en la leche... pero es difícil encontrarles un punto en común para explicar el origen de la palabra leche ;)

Comment: Eso sí, todas las expresiones son de mala educación y no conviene usarlas en un contexto formal!

Comment: No me importa tres leches. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Leche* se usa en España como sinónimo de [*semen*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/leche) (en contexto coloquial, y con connotación soez).

Según el [Diccionario de eufemismos y de expresiones eufemísticas del español actual](https://books.google.cl/books?id=ChMuFgDEuRMC&lpg=PA106&ots=bF70AR0qc-&dq=leche&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q=leche&f=false) es un sintagma (cumple la misma función que un conjunto de otras palabras) en el contexto de interjecciones vulgares. Se usa como reemplazo menos *violento* al nombre de Dios en la expresión original. Algunas de esas expresiones son blasfemas, otras soeces, y otras cambian la blasfemia o lo soez por un eufemismo: *me cago en diez*, *¡ostras!*, etc.

Por extensión, estos mismos sintagmas se usan para significar muchas cosas, entre otras, [*golpe*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N2tsDWF). Así, *darse una ostra*, *darse una leche*. El proceso de cómo llegó a ese significado no está muy documentado (quizá por ser algo tan propio del habla coloquial), pero existen hipótesis al respecto (por ejemplo, aquí: [dar una hostia](http://www.1de3.es/2008/02/28/dar-una-hostia/)).

Comment: En mi opinión es muy común asociar golpes con juramentos, no sólo en España ni sólo en castellano y lo considero una explicación natural satisfactoria a falta de una más académica.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el artículo [Origen de la expresion "mala leche"](http://www.taringa.net/posts/info/2643490/Origen-de-la-expresion-mala-leche.html):

> Tener mala leche o ser mala leche
>
> Esta expresión deriva en realidad de otra que reza "Ser de mala leche" y hace referencia a la costumbre egoísta que tenían las mujeres ricas o nobles en la Edad Media y posteriormente de entregar a sus hijos a nodrizas para que los amamantasen y así no perder las damas el tiempo ni la figura en tan incómoda tarea. La figura de la nodriza era muy común en casi todas las aldeas y ciudades medievales: se trataba de matronas que desde el nacimiento de su primer hijo se dedicaban a dar de mamar a otros de tal modo que nunca perdían la leche de sus pechos.
>
> Algunas de ellas podían ser judías o moriscas, de ahí que "ser de mala leche" indicaba haber sido amamantado por una de ellas, de manera que sus vicios y su baja ralea habían pasado al pequeño, manifestándose en una conducta poco cristiana. Usábase así la expresión como insulto...

Como se ve, al final habla de que se usaba como un insulto. En cambio, la frase *dar leche* en España tiene como hipótesis la misma historia solo que les amenazaban con dar leche de otras personas como insulto hasta que terminó siendo usado como golpe.